# The set of all covectors fields and the dual to the set of all vector fields, isomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle, module-isomorphism

Given a smooth manifold $M$, the space of smooth sections of the tangent bundle is denoted by $\Gamma(TM)$ and the space of smooth sections of the cotangent bundle $\Gamma(T^* M)$. Both $\Gamma(TM)$ and $\Gamma(T^* M)$ are $C^{\infty}(M)$-modules. Then, there is also the dual to $\Gamma(TM)$, that we denote $\Gamma(TM)^*$, another $C^{\infty}(M)$-module.

How can I prove that $\Gamma(TM)^*$ and $\Gamma(T^*M)$ are isomorphic as $C^{\infty}(M)$-modules?

Comment: No, the tangent bundle is denoted $TM$ and the cotangent bundle is denoted $T^*M$. The $\Gamma$ denotes global sections ... Your title is not right. The cotangent bundle *is* the dual of the tangent bundle. You are asking about why the module of global sections of $T^*M$ is isomorphic to the dual of the module of global sections of $TM$.

Comment: Pick a Riemann metric on M and use it to construct an isomorphism of vector bundles from TM to T^*M. Then what you want follows at once.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't see how it does.

Comment: @TedShifrin. Thank you for the remark, my mistake. Then, what is the name of $\Gamma(TM)$? A shorter name than "The global sections of the cotangent bundle and the dual to the global sections of the tangent bundle". Even, writing "The set of all covectors fields and the dual to the set of all vector fields", is kind of long.

Comment: I don't know a shortcut. For any vector bundle $E$, $\Gamma(E)$ is the set/vector space ... of global sections of $E$.

Comment: $\Gamma(TM)$ is the set of vector fields (sometimes denoted $\mathfrak{X}(M)$), and $\Gamma(T^*M)$ is the set of $1$-forms, or covector fields, denoted $\Omega^1(M)$.

Comment: @Pedro doesn't the identification of $\Gamma(T^*M)$ with the set of $1$-forms $\Omega^1(M)$ require a theorem? I usually don't see 1-forms defined as sections of the cotangent bundle, I mean. (I grant you that these two things are equivalent, of course. I found this question while looking for Lagrange's question while reading about cotangent bundles in a diff. geo. book--Spivak's--for the first time. Previously all I knew about cotangent bundles was that their global sections are global 1-forms...)

Comment: @Lagrange.el.Ciencia In general (even if Pedro rightly complains that I'm getting caught up in semantics) you want to understand $\Gamma$ as referring to sections of a (more generally) sheaf of some kind on a space (e.g. a manifold, algebraic variety, scheme, etc.). The sections are global in the sense that you are taking the sections which are defined on the entire space rather than on some open set in the space. You can see Vakil's book for several (three-ish?) different notations for $\Gamma$ which are all equivalent, but certainly I think it would behoove you to accustom yourself to lingo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a natural map $\Phi : \Gamma(T^* M) \to \Gamma(TM)^*$ given by

$$ \Phi(\alpha)(X) = \alpha(X) $$

This is obviously $C^\infty(M)$-linear, and it's not hard to show that it is injective. The (slightly) more difficult part is to show surjectivity. Consider some $\xi \in \Gamma(TM)^*$. We want to define $\alpha \in \Gamma(T^* M)$ the following way: given a tangent vector $X_{x_0} \in T_{x_0} M$, we extend it to a (smooth) vector field $X \in \Gamma(TM)$, and then set $\alpha(X_{x_0}) = \xi(X)(x_0)$.

This would clearly do the trick, but it's not obvious that $\alpha$ is well-defined, because we made an arbitrary choice of how to extend $X_{x_0}$ into the vector field $X$. If you ponder it a bit you'll see that to show $\alpha$ is well-defined it suffices to show that, if $X_{x_0} = 0$, then for any extension $X$ we will have $\xi(X)(x_0) = 0$. This is where $\xi$ being $C^\infty(M)$-linear comes in. I'm gonna be a bit sketchy.

Using a bump function argument it's not hard to show that $\xi(X)(x_0)$ only depends on the values of $X$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. This allows you to assume there's a local basis of tangent vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ and so we can express $X = X^1 e_1 + \cdots + X^n e_n$ with each $X^i \in C^\infty(M)$. Note that $X^1(x_0) = \ldots = X^n(x_0) = 0$. Since

$$ \xi(X) = X^1 \xi(e_1) + \cdots + X^n \xi(e_n) $$

we clearly have $\xi(X)(x_0) = X^1(x_0) \xi(e_1)(x_0) + \cdots + X^n(x_0) \xi(e_n)(x_0) = 0$, which finishes the argument.

Observation: Don't forget to prove that $\alpha$ is actually smooth.

Comment: Thank you, I understood. Is there a book where I can find this?

Comment: I don't know a book with this specifically. The argument is pretty much the same as for the fact that, for a connection $\nabla$, the term $\nabla_X Y$ depends on $X$ only pointwise and on $Y$ only locally. You can find that in many books; I know it's written out in detail in Lee's Riemannian Manifolds book.

Comment: Also, if you've understood everything, you should consider accepting the answer.